# How to save the request.getAttribute value?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Hi i tried to get value entered in one page to another page,it is working fine and showing the value but when i am trying to save the value then it is showing me null in console,actullay my requirement is in first page i have to enter Mobilenumber in one field and press next then i have to redirect it to another page which is having some other fields like firstname and lastname,there i have a mobile number field where i have to get mobile number which is entered in previous page as a disabled field,i am succeed to get the value and showing.

i tried this in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/firstpage")
    public ModelAndView Validate(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String mobile_No = request.getParameter("mobileNo");
        ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView();
        request.setAttribute("mobile_No", mobile_No);
        modelAndView.setViewName("secondpage");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

this is second page method to validate the entered values

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/register")
    public ModelAndView newAccount(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        String first_Name = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String last_Name = request.getParameter("lastName");
        String mobile_No = request.getParameter("mobile_No");

                ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
                modelAndView.addObject("first_Name",first_Name);
        modelAndView.addObject("last_Name",last_Name);
        modelAndView.addObject("mobile_No",mobile_No);

         modelAndView.setViewName("success");
             return modelAndView;
         }
```

this is my first page where i enter only mobile number

```
<form name="registration_form" id="registration_form" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/firstpage" method="post" >

            <label for="mobileNo" class="control-label"><b>Mobile Number:</b><span class="f_req">*</span></label>
               <div class="controls">
                 <input type="text" size="60" id="mobileNo" name="mobileNo" class="span8"
                autocomplete="off">
               </div>

    </form>
```

this is my jsp page where i am showing mobile number

```
<form name="registration_form" id="registration_form" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register" method="post">

                    <label for="mobileNo" class="control-label"><b>Mobile Number:</b><span class="f_req">*</span></label>
                       <div class="controls">
                         <input type="text" size="60" id="mobile_no" name="mobile_no" class="span8"
                         autocomplete="off" value="<%=request.getAttribute("mobile_No")%>" disabled="disabled">
                       </div>


                    <label for="firstName" class="control-label"><b>First Name:</b><span class="f_req">*</span></label>
                       <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" size="60" id="firstName" name="firstName" class="span8"
                        value="${first_Name}" autocomplete="off">
                       </div>


                    <label for="lastName" class="control-label"><b>Last Name:</b><span class="f_req">*</span></label>
                       <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" size="60" id="lastName" name="lastName" class="span8"
                        value="${last_Name}">
                       </div>
    </form>
```

Please help me i am not able to find out my mistake.thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `<%=request.getAttribute("mobile_No")%>` instead of `${mobile_NO}`?

Comment: i am using it to show the previous page entered mobile number,is it wrong geoand?if i keep as u mentioned now mobile is not showing in imput field,it is showing empty

Comment: It's untuitive. You are using ${first_Name} and ${last_Name} so why not use ${mobile_NO} also?

Comment: for mobile field iam using this <%=request.getAttribute("mobile_No")%> because i have to show the value which is entered in previous page,no need to enter second time

Comment: I agree completely, but try to replace it with `${mobile_NO}` and see what happens

Comment: if i keep ${mobile_No} then i am getting the number which i entered that is fine,but my requirement is different,what exactly is in first page i enter mobile number and submit i get ONE TIME PASSWORD to and redirect to next page ,in that page i have to get same mobile number as disabled mode with 2 more fields.

Comment: Ok, try changing `name="mobile_no"` to `name="mobile_No"` in the second page and let me know what happens

Comment: No success geoand still i am getting null value

Comment: Can you share your project on GitHub or something?

Comment: sorry geoand i cannot share complete project, i hope you understand

Comment: Your problem is, you are not able to get the mobile number submitted from the second page to the controller, right?

Comment: Then change disabled="disabled" to readonly, you can not send the value of a disabled field

Comment: thanks a lot Raju working exactly what i want.thanks for your help

Comment: @RajuRudru You should add thay as an answer so future readers can find it easily

Comment: Ok @Geoand :) I'm adding

Comment: @RajuRudru Good! You can also mention that one could use readonly for disabling the ability to edit the number :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `disabled="disabled"` attribute in your input tag for the mobile number field in second page.  You can not send the value of a field which is disabled.

Even if you try it will be sent as null value. So try changing the `disabled="disabled"` to `readonly="readonly"`.  It may solve your problem.

Comment: Raju i am facing one more problem here suppose if i refresh the page or validating without entering any of firstname or lastname  then mobile number is going and showing null in place of number.

Comment: Refresh the page means, is it after form submission?

Comment: At the time of refreshing the page, it is again sending a form submission request and at that time since there is no request attribute "mobile_No" it will be treated as "" (empty string). Empty String will be treated as null when you submit the form. In order to avoid this problem, instead of simply returning "success" view, you can write another method to display success page and from your newAccount method redirect to the method that displays success page. In this case when you refresh the page it won't submit the form

Answer (score 0):

Well in the first page you do request.setAttribute; the the attibute is put in and input text with name and id **mobile_no**
In the second page you do: `request.getPatameter("mobile_No")`

It's wrong...you should do `request.getPatameter("mobile_no")` (please not the n and not N)

I hope this helps
Angelo

Comment: Hi Angelo i tried as you mention but still i am getting null if i print that string value

Answer (score 0):

In the second page where you are trying to retrieve the values, I think

```
    String mobile_No = request.getParameter("mobile_No");
```

Should be

```
    String mobile_No = request.getAttribute("mobile_No");
```

Comment: i tried as u said Still getting the same null value.